# Get coordinates of a DataGridViewRow in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to create a function to get the left and right coordinates of a data row for `Graphics.DrawLine()`.

```
(int x, int y) GetCoordinate(DataGridViewRow row, char leftOrRight)
{
    if (leftOrRight == "L") {
        return ( ) // the left coordinates or current row if visible, 
                   // or the coordinates of the header line if it's not visible
    }
    else if (leftOrRight == "R") {
        return ( ) // the right coordinates or current row if visible, 
                   // or the coordinates of the header line if it's not visible
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var (x1, y1) = GetCoordinate(row1); // a row from data grid view 1
var (x2, y2) = GetCoordinate(row2); // a row from data grid view 2
graphics.DrawLine(pen, x1, y1, x2, y2);
```

How to get the coordinates from the object `DataGridViewRow`?

Comment: Use the proper event and the `RowBounds` is a supplied variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below functions to get the (right,top) and (left,bottom) - which is a bounding box of the current row.

by using width and height, you can easily deduct coordinates of all four corners.

```
    //X-cordiante of (right,top)
    double right = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.AccessibilityObject.Bounds.Right;
    //Y-cordiante of (right,top)
    double top = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.AccessibilityObject.Bounds.Top;
    //X-cordinate of (left,bottom)
    double left = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.AccessibilityObject.Bounds.Left;
    //Y-cordinate of (left,bottom)
    double bottom = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.AccessibilityObject.Bounds.Bottom;
```